# How can I start two processes simultaneously?

Tags: php, parallel-processing

I would like to start using thread with PHP.
Could someone give me an example about how to start two simultaneous processes?

Comment: Threads and processes are [different things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science)#Threads_compared_with_processes).. which do you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to spawn multiple PHP processes that run in the background (or not), you should have a look at the manual entry on Program Execution. It lists all the methods that allow you to spawn a new process to handle background tasks

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php

Answer (score 1):

You can fork processes with PCNTL extension. http://php.net/manual/tr/book.pcntl.php

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid) {
     // main
     pcntl_wait($status);
} else {
     // child
}
```